# Password Enforce the avoidance of common words such as days, months etc

Tags: .net, validation, passwords, change-password

We have been asked to add password strength validation into our system from a customer. All they have asked for is that the password is at least 8 characters long and that is does not include "Common words such as days, months etc".

Does anyone know of any algorithms or examples that would cover this level of password strength testing?

Thanks

Comment: Am using vb.net but I can convert if needed.

Comment: have you tried my solution? I just imported the library you need to add (the other 4 already come here when I open a project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not download any of the text lists of 'passwords' (which will include many, many dictionary words also) from the internet. Do a search in google for wordlists AND passwords, I'm sure you'll get a good hit.

1. Load the list into a collection.
2. Get a password from the user
3. Use LINQ to compare the 'incoming' password isn't contained in the collection.
4. If it is; ask for a new password and loop back to (2)
5. If it isn't; use that password.

Using an external list means that they can keep updating the list of not allowed passwords dynamically - rather than hardcoding it as in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions for matching the names.... the length is easy (just check the Length property)... here is an example on how to catch if it has one of the days inside of it...

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class tester
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] NotValid = { "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday",};

        string password = "Monday5";

        bool isvalid = password.Length > 7;
        foreach (string s in NotValid)
            if (Regex.IsMatch(password, "^.*" + s + ".*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                isvalid = false;

        if(!isvalid)
             Console.WriteLine("Your password doesn't match our strength requirements");
    }
}
```

If your password contains any of the words in the NotValid array then isValid will be false...

You can find more info about c# regex's [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)